# If $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=-1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x)=1$ then following holds?

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=-1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x)=1$ do we have $-1\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)\leq 1$?
In this case we can't apply squeeze theorem but I am not sure about this.

Edit: $f(x), g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are not necessarily continuous but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)$ does exists.

Comment: Only if $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exists.

Comment: @nicomezi How about in general cases when functions are not necessarily continuous?

Comment: @MartinR So it is true even when functions are not continuous but limit of $g(x)$ does exists at $0$? I tried to come up with an counter examples but I failed to visualize.

Comment: I was wrong, I thought you wanted $g(0)$ to be in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the problem is properly stated, i.e., "given

1. $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $x$
2. limits for all three, as $x \to 0$, exist,

can we say that $K = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ is between $-1$ and $1$?", it's relatively easy.

Lemma: if $q(x) \ge 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} q(x) = L$ exists, then $L \ge 0$. In short: a nonnegative function can only have a nonnegative limit.

Proof: Suppose $L$ is negative. Then picking $\epsilon = \frac{L}{2}$, there must be a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies $|q(x) - L| < \epsilon = \frac{L}{2}$. But this latter statement is the same as
$$
\frac{L}{2} \le q(x) \le \frac{3L}{2}.
$$
The outer two numbers are negative, hence the middle one must be as well, and that's a contradiction, so our assumption ("$L$ is negative") must be false, and the lemma is proved.

Let's apply that lemma to $q(x) = h(x) - g(x)$. It tells us that
\begin{align}
0 
&\le \lim_{x \to 0} (h(x) - g(x))\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} h(x) - \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) & \text{because both limits exist}\\
&= 1 - K 
\end{align}
Adding $K$ to both sides gives $K \le 1$, i.e., $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) \le 1$$.

Now we can apply the same lemma to $q(x) = g(x) - f(x)$, and find that
$$K \ge -1,$$
by similar algebra steps, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Could you say that $\lim | g (x) | \leq 1$. Since $-1 \leq g (x) \leq 1$ which would imply that $ | g (x) | \leq 1 $ and applying the inequality of limits should that $\lim | g (x) | \leq 1$, I don't know what other hypotheses there are about $ g(x) $.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily true.  $g(x)$ may not have a limit at $0$.  Consider a piece-wise function like $g(x)=1/2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $g(x)=-1/2$ for $x<0$.  If $f(x)=x^2-1$ and $h(x)=x^2+1$, then the hypothesis holds, but $g(x)$ doesn't have a limit at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t conclude any thing, since the hipotesis of the theorem is that $\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)}=L$ and $\lim_{x \to a}{f(x)}=L$ then you cant conclude that $\lim_{x \to a}{h(x)=L}$. So I think that you only can asegure that $\lim_{x \to 0}{g(x)}$ exists and $L\in [-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=-1$ and $h(x)=1$
$g(x)=\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$
$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=T$

$T$ doesn't exist.